# Как сравнить две переменные типа record?

Tags: delphi

```
type cl = record
  r,g,b:byte;
end;

var cl1,cl2:cl;
begin

if cl1<>cl2 then ...  //operator not applicable to this operand type
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может так сравнишь рекордные переменные...

```
if (cl1.r=cl2.r) and (cl1.g=cl2.g) and (cl1.b=cl2.b) then 
... 
else 
... 
{пиши код свой, если переменные не идентичны}
```

Answer (score 4):

С помощью определения операторов сравнения. RTFM [Operator Overloading](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi)).

См. пример как раз с цветом [Delphi operator overloading](http://www.pritaeas.net/view/articles/delphi-operator-overloading)

ЗЫ Доступно в Delphi старше 7й версии.

ЗЗЫ [Тут](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/34324) список нововведений по сравнению с D7.

Comment: Однако, есть и минусы - тяжеловесная и глючная среда, переработанная в худшую сторону документация.

Answer (score 3):

```
type cl = record
  r,g,b:byte;
  class operator Equal(a, b: cl): Boolean;
end;

{ ... }

class operator cl.Equal(a, b: cl): Boolean; 
begin
  Result := (a.r = b.r)
    and (a.g = b.g)
    and (a.b = b.b);
end;
```

(страшенный стиль кода - авторская копипаста)

Comment: @Asen, это перегрузка оператора.

Comment: Это по сути, обычная функция сравнения двух объектов. Кстати, код не заработает, так как в записях нельзя определять функций, классов( который, кстати, в этом коде определен полностью неверно ) и процедур.

Comment: Я все понял. Вы живете до сих пор в Delphi 7. Или просто не в курсе.

В любом случае потрудитесь зайти и почитать [первоисточники](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/34324).

Comment: В данном конкретном случае @karmadro4 перегрузил оператор `=`.

Comment: Еще раз говорю, что это не сработает в Delphi, так как даже определение класса неверное, несмотря на то, что классы НЕЛЬЗЯ определять в записях.

Comment: @Nofate, лучше [такая ссылка](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Operator_Overloading_%28Delphi%29). К сожалению, Asen снова снова стремится свести дискуссию к простому отрицанию сказанного оппонентом, думаю, что можно его игнорировать.

Comment: Поэтому, кстати, мне и не нравится синтаксис статических членов класса, который они придумали. Взяли бы ключевое слово `static` как у всех (Java/C++/C#). А то `class` внутри определения типа очень смущает, учитывая тот факт, что можно определять внутренние классы.

Comment: @Nofate, согласен, довольно неказисто получилось (как и во многих других нововведениях в дельфёвом диалекте), но я не согласен насчет заимствования ключевых слов из языков семейства Си. Вообще, `static` это модификатор, имеющее другое [значение](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods#Class_Static_Methods). Кстати, зацените, как подошли к вопросу перегрузки операторов архитекты [fpc](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refch15.html).

Answer (score 2):

Сравнение таких переменных как правило зависит от бизнес логики, только при полном равенстве всех полей можно утверждать, что они равны, иначе надо следовать некой бизнес-логике. Приведите пожалуйста бизнес-логику вашего конкретного случая.
Если как догадались другие участники это сравнение двух цветов тогда проще всего наверно сделать процедуру

```
function compareRGB(color1,color2:cl):boolean;
begin
  if color1.r=color2.r and color1.g=color2.g and color1.b=color2.b then 
    result := true
  else
    result := false;
end;
```

Comment: Смешно: "Бизнес логика"! =))))) просто стратегия. Это вы правильно приметили...

Comment: IMHO у автора вопроса RGB (цвет). 

Не знаю, как для бизнеса, а в смысле ощущения человеком яркости что-то вроде 30\*R+50\*G+20\*B.

Тогда можно возвращать 0 если равно, -1 color1 < color2 и 1 если color1 > color2 (или даже разность  оценок яркости).

Comment: Несколько странный синтаксис. А главное - boolshit, conditional statement здесь вообще не нужен.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать RTTI:

```
uses
  SysUtils, RTTI;

type
  Trec = record
    Field1: Integer;
    Field2: string;
    // Добавьте остальные поля по необходимости
  end;

function CompareRecords(const A, B: Trec): Boolean;
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  fieldType: TRttiType;
  field: TRttiField;
begin
  Result := True;

  ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  try
    fieldType := ctx.GetType(TypeInfo(Trec));

    for field in fieldType.GetFields do
    begin
      // Проверка на совпадение значений полей
      if not field.GetValue(@A).Equals(field.GetValue(@B)) then
      begin
        Result := False;
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    ctx.Free;
  end;
end;

// Пример использования:
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  rec1, rec2: Trec;
begin
  // Инициализация записей
  rec1.Field1 := 42;
  rec1.Field2 := 'Hello';

  rec2.Field1 := 42;
  rec2.Field2 := 'World';

  // Сравнение записей
  if CompareRecords(rec1, rec2) then
    ShowMessage('Записи совпадают')
  else
    ShowMessage('Записи не совпадают');
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Подход [@integralal](/users/3549/integralal) - сравнение по полям - правильный. Если хочется этого избежать, можно сравнивать массивы байтов функцией CompareMem, предварительно объявив записи как packed.

```
var 
   p1, p2 : PSomeRecord; 
begin 
   New(p1); 
   New(p2); 
   try 
     if CompareMem(p1, p2, Sizeof(p1^)) then 
       {...}; 
   finally 
     Dispose(p1); 
     Dispose(p2); 
   end; 
end;
```

Чтобы метод работал, записи должны плотно упаковываться и не содержать указателей. Вообще метод небезопасный.

Comment: А почему нельзя сравнивать записи с указателями?

Comment: Потому что указатели могут указывать в разные участки памяти, а содержимое в них может быть одинаковым. `CompareMem` сравнит только сами указатели.

Answer (score 1):

```
function IsEqual(a,b:C1): Boolean;
begin
  Result:=(a.r=b.r) and (a.g=b.g) and (a.b=b.b);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

В Delphi 2006 и выше есть перегрузка операторов для рекордов:

```
TKMPoint = record
  X,Y: Integer;
public
  class operator Equal(const A, B: TKMPoint): Boolean;
  class operator NotEqual(const A, B: TKMPoint): Boolean;
end;

.........  

class operator TKMPoint.Equal(const A, B: TKMPoint): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (A.X = B.X) and (A.Y = B.Y);
end;


class operator TKMPoint.NotEqual(const A, B: TKMPoint): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (A.X <> B.X) or (A.Y <> B.Y);
end;

........

var
  A, B: TKMPoint;
begin
   A := TKMPoint.New(1, 1);
   B := TKMPoint.New(1, 1);
   Assert(A = B);
   B := TKMPoint.New(2, 2);
   Assert(A <> B);
end;
```

Список операторов для переопределения: [Operator Overloading (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi))